# Index out of range with multiple lists on same line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given

```py
>>> foo = [1, 1]
>>> bar = [1, 1, 1]
>>> print(foo[5], bar[5])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I tell which list threw the exception?

For more non-trivial examples, this is very irritating. Can someone explain how the Python interpreter works so that it can't remember the character it is on? This seems like too obvious of a design error, so there must be a reason for it, right?

Comment: In this case, of course, they would BOTH throw an exception.  Remember that the code is compiled to an intermediate language before it is executed.  If there's a syntax error, it knows the character.  If there's a runtime error, it doesn't.

Comment: Python executes code from top to bottom, from left to right (with some exceptions). In your example, there isn't really a way to separate which of the two lists threw the error, but if you had say a `list` and a `str` in there, and the `str` was the one that caused the error, then you would find it really quick.

Comment: Actually I want to know if interpreter executes the first part or the second part.

Comment: @TimRoberts sure but say I'm querying 4 lists on the same line and I have no visibility on the length or contents of any of them, then what? Also iirc JavaScript is able to tell me the character number of these kinds of errors but I may be wrong

Comment: @qewfsdqeg I think there's a worthwhile fundamental question underlying this! Both Python and JavaScript are compiled into intermediate forms that are then executed in a virtual machine. JavaScript does point to the column number when an error is thrown; why can't Python?

Comment: @mgiuffrida Thank you for the clarification, I'm unknowing of language internals and a deep dive on this would be awesome. I haven't written JS in a while so I don't have an example of an exception as described previously on hand, but I will go and find one if necessary.

Comment: I suppose the short answer is performance.  That's always been a key driver for Python, not so much for Javascript.  It would be very costly to maintain character information in the intermediate language.  Better to add some extra debug lines when this kind of exception occurs to refine the issue.

Comment: @MSH set a string variable "code_block" equal to the three lines of code above then `import dis` and finally `print(dis.dis(compile(code_block, "", "exec")))`. I see the parameters evaluated left to right.

Comment: @qewfsdqeg If you split your print statement across multiple lines you will see exactly which list throws the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JonSG's answer will work for all versions of Python. In the future however, Python 3.11+ will store column offsets in its bytecode. The traceback will underline the expression that errored:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\module.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(foo[5], bar[5])
          ~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is thanks to [PEP 657](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0657/) implemented in Python 3.11, currently in alpha, and set to release in October 2022.

Note that this feature carries with it a small memory cost, and the authors have acknowledged that, saying:

> We understand that the extra cost of this information may not be acceptable for some users, so we propose an opt-out mechanism which will cause generated code objects to not have the extra information while also allowing pyc files to not include the extra information.

One can opt-out of this feature by passing `-Xno_debug_ranges` to `python`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can force it by splitting your print statement across multiple lines (though I agree it is more a workaround than a real solution):

```
foo = [1, 1]
bar = [2, 2]
print(
    foo[5],
    bar[5]
)
```

Should result in something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    foo[5],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note as well that the `dis` module might be of help here if one wanted to actually inspect the byte code to see what was happening:

```
import dis

code_block ='''
foo = [1, 1]
bar = [2, 2]
print(foo[5], bar[5])
'''

print(dis.dis(compile(code_block, "", "exec")))
```

Tells me:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 BUILD_LIST               2
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             12 BUILD_LIST               2
             14 STORE_NAME               1 (bar)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             18 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
             20 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             22 BINARY_SUBSCR
             24 LOAD_NAME                1 (bar)
             26 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             28 BINARY_SUBSCR
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             32 POP_TOP
             34 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

So, on my platform `foo[5]` is evaluated (via BINARY_SUBSCR) prior to bar.

Comment: [not just on your platform](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

Answer (score 0):

I while back I wrote replacement using decompilation to show locations in tracebacks. See [loctraceback](https://pypi.org/project/loctraceback/). It hasn't gotten much attention and I haven't tried using it in a while.

The [trepan3k](https://pypi.org/project/trepan3k) debugger also uses decompilation to show you more precisely where you are as well when stopped.

I gave a small talk on the technology used here a while back in 2018. Interestingly when I gave examples like this, e.g. https://rocky.github.io/pycon2018.co/#/2. One comment I got in the questions is that why would you ever need something like this.

Nowadays, I tend to improve things only to the extent of my own personal need, interest, and time and worry less about others. (And, after all, open-source work should mean others could contribute as well.)